# Enum for checking UI states and enforcing checking of each name

Tags: java, android, enums

I have a legacy code for an Android app that was passed on from another team to us and has some code that desperately requires a rewrite or at least some amount of refactoring and clean up. Having said that, we are at a position in our schedule where we are gearing up for a release next month.

The problem I am facing is that there is an Enum that is maintained with all the possible UI states that the system can have, based on some preconditions. It was an effort to implement a State machine. On every subsequent screen after the state has been determined we are checking the state in a switch case and determine what the screen is supposed to do and also make wordage changes. So, I have these switch case all over the code in different Activities and Fragments. I can't create a single method out of the switch case as each screen is supposed to do something different. Everything works well if all screen are coded accordingly but the problem begins when we have a new UI State, we add the state to the Enum but teammates sometimes forget to check the new state in their respective code, basically adding the new state in the switch case in their activities/fragments and that results in bugs. Is there a way I can enforce this checking through code just like interface methods need to be implemented by the implementing class? If a new state was added we would have compilation errors in the code. If this is attainable using a different data structure I am will to make that change. 
The Enum at this point is just a regular Enum like,

```
public static enum UIStates{
PASSWORD_UNKNOWN,
CANCEL,
FAILURE,
SKIP,
DEVICE_UNKNOWN,
...
...
... 22 other states
}
```

Comment: if you remove the default case in your switches, you'll be forced by the compiler to consider all cases. that could be a possibility, if I understand your issue correctly

Comment: But even if  somehow you enforce the checking in all of the activity you still have to provide a different code that handel each state and as you said every activity have it's own behaviour so I don't think that you can do that

Comment: @njzk2 - It would be possible with Eclipse and the compile-time warning and I think the setting has to be turned on explicitly. We use Android Studio for development and I can't find that option and also it does not work in default compiler warnings/error rules, where ever they are set. Thank you for answering, I am grateful to you but I was looking for a fool proof solution. If some one forgets to change the compiler options or restores their settings we would still end up getting bugs.

Comment: I guess you can have that option on the compiler of your continuous integration server.

Comment: @Mahmoud.M - That's the whole idea. I want to provide explicit code so that the particular case is handled in the right way. I am trying to avoid  having bugs because we went to default. I rather have compilation errors so that it gets people's attention rather than having bugs. Thank you for looking into it.

Comment: @luckylukein are all the activitys or fragments in your project check the UI state

Comment: @Mahmoud.M - Not all Activiites and Fragments but a lot of them have to check the UI State. After the UI state is determined I have about 22 screen that have the checking. As design changes more screens might be added. Thanks!

Comment: @njzk2 - Yeah! that's a good suggestion. I understand that there is no direct solution to the problem. Adding the compiler check in the continuous integration server would help as daily builds would catch the issue and the checking has to be done in one place. Let me investigate in that direction. It's not the most ideal solution but it is a workable solution. Thank you for your help!